# Binary Search Tree Recursion and malloc

Tags: c, recursion, malloc, binary-search-tree

I am having an issue adding to my binary search tree, my program seems to be adding to a temporary structure instead. I think that in order for it to work correctly I have to call malloc for the left and right nodes before I set  the variable node to part of the structure. I am just not sure where in the code to use malloc so the rest of it still works =/

```
 typedef struct BiTree_ {
   BiTreeNode *root;
   int size;
} BiTree;

    typedef struct BitTreeData_ {
   char *str;
   int diff;
   int start_count;
   int end_count;
   int hidden;
} BiTreeData;

 typedef struct BiTreeNode_ {
    BiTreeData *data;
    struct BiTreeNode_ *right;
    struct BiTreeNode_ *left;
} BiTreeNode;

    int
bitree_insert(BiTree *tree, BiTreeNode *node, char *str)
{
    if(tree->root == NULL){
        tree->root = (BiTreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(BiTreeNode*));
        tree->root->data = (BiTreeData*)malloc(sizeof(BiTreeData*));
        tree->root->right = NULL;
        tree->root->left = NULL;
        tree->root->data->str = str;
        tree->root->data->hidden = 0;
        tree->root->data->start_count = 0;
        tree->root->data->end_count = 0;
        tree->root->data->diff = 0;
        tree->size++;
        return 0;
    }    
    if(node == NULL){
        node = (BiTreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(BiTreeNode));
        node->right = (BiTreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(BiTreeNode*));
        node->right = NULL;
        node->left = (BiTreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(BiTreeNode*));
        node->left = NULL;
        node->data = (BiTreeData*)malloc(sizeof(BiTreeData*));
        node->data->str = str;
        node->data->hidden = 0;
        node->data->start_count = 0;
        node->data->end_count = 0;
        node->data->diff = 0;
        tree->size++;
        return 0;
    }
    if(strcmp(str, node->data->str)<0){
        if(node->left == NULL){

            return 0;
        }
                bitree_insert(tree, node->left, str);
    }
    if(strcmp(str, node->data->str)>0){
        if(node->right == NULL){
            return 0;
        }
        bitree_insert(tree, node->right, str);
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The arguments you pass to the function `bitree_insert` are passed by value and not by reference. So, for example, `node` is a pointer to a `BitTreeNode` type variable. If you then assign to `node`, it sets the value of the local variable named node. It seems that what you wanted to do is to pass a reference to a node, i.e. `BitTreeNode **`. That way, when you assign to `*node` that assignment is to the pointer passed from the caller rather than to the local variable.

Comment: Or perhaps you're just missing, when allocating the new node, a call that will add it to the tree (you're allocating a node and incrementing `tree->size` but nowhere adding the node to the tree.

Comment: Hmm, your BitTreeNode ** idea just might work, I'll see if I can adjust the code to fit the new parameter and report back. Thank you.